# Can't read $0 in ForEach

Tags: swiftui

I've got a ForEach that lists an array of colours. In the below example, the Label text will show red, blue etc. but the .foregroundColor modifier doesn't work and defaults to the default in my Color extension.

### ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

var colors = ["red", "blue"]

@State var groupLabelColor: String?

    var body: some view {
           Picker("Colour", selection: $groupLabelColor) {
                ForEach(colors, id: \.self) {
                    Label($0, systemImage: "circle.fill")
                        .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
                        .foregroundColor(Color[$0])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Color.swift

```
import SwiftUI

 extension Color {
      static subscript(name: String) -> Color {
           switch name {
                case "red":
                     return Color.red
                case "blue":
                     return Color.blue
                default:
                     return Color.green
            }
        }
}
```

I don't understand why the Label text works but it won't for the modifier. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Picker` only offers you limited customisation of the labels it uses. One of the things you can't control, with some of the picker styles at least, is the foreground colour. If you used the `.inline` picker style within a list, or if you use the `ForEach` outside the context of a picker, your code works fine.